# posting to facebook page wall on facebook Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to post a messages on my facebook page wall .
i use the the facebook Graph API ( manage_pages and publish_stream )

when i execute my code facebook  display this  error.

Anyone know how to do this, or  my code need changing?????? thanks

this is the error message :
L’URL fournie n’est pas autorisée par la configuration de l’application.: Une ou plusieurs URL fournies ne sont pas autorisées par les paramètres de l’application. Elle(s) doi(ven)t correspondre à l’URL du site ou du Canevas, ou le domaine doit être un sous-domaine de l’un des domaines de l’application.

```
<?php 
require_once 'src/facebook.php';

$appId='4067222xxxxxx';
$secret='deb4246189c15f173252exxxxxxxx';
$returnurl='https://pacific-savannah-xxxx.herokuapp.com/';
$permissions='manage_pages, publish_stream';

$fb=new Facebook(array('appId'=>$appId,'secret'=>$secret));

$fbuser=$fb->getUser();
if($fbuser){

}
else {
    $loginurl=$fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>$permissions,'redirect-uri'=>$returnurl));
    echo '<a href="'.$loginurl.'">Login </a>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application is configured correctly. Go to the [Developer Site](http://developers.facebook.com/apps) and update your settings so that your website URL is entered in the "Website with Facebook Login" section (or other relevant area). Make sure your domain is also included in the "App Domains" field.